# Prove that a specific function is surjective

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Say we have a set S, that contains all the strings

Comment: If it were surjective, there had to exist a string being mapped to '$a$'. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show that the function is surjective, you need to show that for any word $w$, there is some word $w'$ such that $R(w')=w$.

If you want to show that the function is not surjective, you need to show that there is a single word $w$ such that $R(w')\neq w$ for any word $w'$.

Which of those two cases do you think is the correct one?

Comment: I would say that it not surjective ?

Comment: The exercise define the function that way : "f : W → W" ; does it mean that the function is only on W ? In which case, a word with an "a" would be a word such that  R(w′)≠w ?

Comment: @Nao That's exactly what you need to show.  Good job!